# Overwriting __builtins__ function not working with import

Tags: python, python-2.7, built-in

Here, is how i tried to overwrite `__builtins__` function:

```
>>> lisa = __builtins__.list
>>> list('123')
['1', '2', '3']
>>>
```

And it works as i expect.

Now when i tried to overwrite `import` :

```
>>> importing = __builtins__.__import__
>>> importing sys
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    importing sys
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> import sys
<module 'sys' (built-in)>
>>>
```

**Why its not working when i tried to overwrite import ?**

Comment: someone else posted this as a [blog post](http://mathamy.com/import-accio-bootstrapping-python-grammar.html) just recently

Answer (score 3):

You cannot create new keywords and statements in Python; [`import` is a statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement), `importing` is not.

All you did was bind the [`__import__` built-in *function*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) to a new name; you don't even need to use the `__builtins__` module to do that:

```
importing = __import__

sys = importing('sys')
```

The `__builtins__` name is a CPython implementation detail, and has nothing to do with keywords; it is the location Python looks up built-in functions, types and constants instead. Also see the [`__builtin__` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) (no `s`).

To do what you want would require extending the Python parser, to recognize `importing` as an alias for `import`.

Comment: so, is it possible to make it work 'importing sys' ?

Comment: No, not without altering the Python parser.